Is it possible to disable intune for a specific user?
I'm using my work laptop for both work and private stuff. When I'm not working, I'd like to be able to logout from my work account and login with another account, and I'd like to have Microsoft Intune disabled for this account. Is that possible?

Technically yes, but you will run a high risk of the machine being flagged for non-compliance as Intune detects extra usage. Once this happens, you will not be able to access work resources on that machine again until after IT restores access following whatever procedure they have when a device falls outside of compliance.
